# `jQuery.getJSON()` function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have the following code which returns `h=30` instead of each value inside the loop.

```
for (var h = 0; h < 31; h++) {
  $.getJSON('http://google.com/',
    function(data) {
      console.log('line ' + h);
    }
  )
};
```

What do I need to do to get loop values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a closure with an [**IIFE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

```
for (var h = 0; h < 31; h++) {
    (function(h) {
        $.getJSON('http://google.com/', function(data) {......
            console.log('line ' + h);
        })
    })(h)
};
```

That way, the value of `h` will be preserved for that iteration instead of being set to the last value by the time `getJSON` is called back