# Pagination of Youtube Playlist

Tags: javascript, pagination, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-js-client

I have a page named banking.html which displays all the videos from a particular playlist of my YouTube channel. I know that we have to apply pagination to display more than 50 videos but I am not sure how can I do this? If anyone can help me achieving this, I would highly appreciate. Here is my code:

banking.html:

```
<div class="category-section">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1>Banking</h1><span>Latest Upload</span>                        
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul id="youtube-playlist-feed_1" class="thumbnail-section">
                    </ul>
                    <div id="nextPage"></div>
                    <div id="prevPage"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

banking.js:

```
                var htmlString = "";
            var apiKey = 'AIzaSyA7dAzzNvPCxTSsSGiV7dvoj3rkt0qbdXg';
            var playlistID = 'PLBhKKjnUR0XBVrHvtDOylN5XREHh9X1nt';
            var maxResults = 50;

            var playlists = [{
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKnQmapkDs7x47jkr-nw3l50',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_1'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKmIBkoopKFK4kTTOmC1Zof0',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_2'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLBhKKjnUR0XAM2Wvi7JY5gLRpFLzIE-An',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_3'
              }
            ];

            playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
              getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlist.playlistId, playlist.el);
            })

            function getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlistId, el) {
              $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + apiKey + '&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&part=snippet&maxResults=' + (maxResults > 50 ? 50 : maxResults), function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                  var videoID = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                  var title = item['snippet']['title'];
                  var pub = item['snippet']['publishedAt'];
                  var nextPage = item['snippet']['nextPageToken'];
                  var videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID + '&list=' + playlistID + '&index=1';
                  htmlString += '<div class="video-wrap"><div class="video"><a target="_blank" href="player.html?vid='+videoID+'" ><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + videoID + '/mqdefault.jpg"></a></div>' + '<div class="title"><a target="_blank" id="player" href="player.html?vid='+videoID+'">' + title + '</a></div></div>';

                });
                $(el).html(htmlString);

                htmlString = '';
              });
            }
```

Comment: What does not work with your current solution?

Comment: I have declare var nextPage, but how should I append it?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the maximum number of resources the server returns in the response to a list request by setting the maxResults field. If the total number of items exceeds this maximum, the server returns one page of results.

Remember that maxResults does not guarantee the number of results on one page. Incomplete results can be detected by a non-empty nextPageToken field in the result. In order to retrieve the next page, perform the exact same request as previously and append a pageToken field with the value of nextPageToken from the previous page. A new nextPageToken is provided on the following pages until all the results are retrieved.

For example, here is a query followed by the query for retrieving the next page of results in a paginated list:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?pageToken=[nextPageTokenFrom previous request]
```

**Tips to fix your code**

As shown above you will need to add the next page token to the request you are looping though.   You are already testing on maxresult you could make a test that checks if nextpage exists then you add it if not you stop. I do not claim to be a Javascript dev but it should be close to this.

```
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + apiKey + '&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&part=snippet&maxResults=' + (maxResults > 50 ? 50 : maxResults + (nextPage != null ? 'pageToken=' + [nextPageTokenFrom previous request] : ''
), function(data) {
```

Comment: I know that, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Its not default supported by your libray https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/164  you will have to create the loop on your own theres no propagation method if thats what your looking for.

Comment: that's what I am concerned about. How can I create a loop in my code I have explained above?

Comment: Thats a different question Your question was about how to do pagination.  You might want to ask a question about how to do loops in javascript as thats really not related to the api   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Can anyone help me please?

Comment: @DalmTo  This is definitely related to API as I need to call API in the loop.

Comment: check update I am not a javascript expert i am a google api expert thats why I recommend you open another question about how to use loops in javascript..   I can really only answer your question based upon the api and how it works.   I can give you tips on how to get it working with JavaScript but thats about it my javascript skills are beginner at best.

Comment: Like i mentioned you should open another question for assistance with looping in JavaScript.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212423/jquery-getjson-function-inside-a-for-loop  or just look around on stack there are a number of anwsers

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of the solution in php.  It can be altered to match your use-case and others.

It calls the API for titles in a specific playlist, paginating iteratively. It uses the nextPageToken value from the previous API call JSON response to populate the "pageToken" parameter in a new call. Use maxResults to cover all items in the playlist.

I'm using this to log a clean list of titles in a playlist.

```
<?php 
$playlistId = 'Enter_Your_Playlist_Id_here';
$access_token = 'Enter_Your_Token_Id_here';
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlistId.'&key='.$access_token.'&maxResults=50';
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($response->items as $playlist){
$title = $playlist->snippet->title;
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<p><?php echo $title;?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php 
$playlistId = 'Enter_Your_Playlist_Id_here';
$access_token = 'Enter_Your_Access_Token_here';
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlistId.'&key='.$access_token.'&pageToken=Enter_the_nextPageToken_value_from_previous_API_Call_Here&maxResults=50';
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($response->items as $playlist){
$title = $playlist->snippet->title;
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<p><?php echo $title;?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```